# github custom domain doesn't work

Tags: github, dns

I have made a cname for my blog and uploaded a cname file to my master branch.But It doesn't work.It display page does not exist all the time.
My dns is parked in cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit the `CNAME` file to the root of your `gh-pages` branch for custom domains to work.

Comment: I have saw the help document of github many times(http://pages.github.com/).If I create "User & Organization Pages",there is no gh-pages branch except master branch.

Answer (score 0):

You must first create the gh-pages Branch. The easiest way to do this is via the Automatic Generator. A starter guide can be found here: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-pages-with-the-automatic-generator